# How to set web.config settings when selfhosting WebApi as a TopShelf windows service

Tags: asp.net-web-api, owin, self-hosting, katana, topshelf

I have a self hosted web api running as a windows service using TopShelf.  I have an app.config for TopShelf but no web.config for my web api. If I add a web.config or add settings (web settings) to the app.config both are ignored by my web api.

I need to set the following:

```
<system.web><identity impersonate="true" /></system.web>
```

but I have no idea where to set it.

Answer (score 0):

You're not hosting your web api in `IIS` so you don't need a `web.config`.
You cannot use:

```
<system.web><identity impersonate="true" /></system.web>
```

as it is specific to `ASP.NET` (more details [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/72wdk8cc(v=vs.100).aspx)).

Why don't you set your credentials in the windows service => "Log On" configuration ?

[image]

Or, using **TopShelf**, by [code](http://docs.topshelf-project.com/en/latest/configuration/config_api.html#service-start-modes):

```
HostFactory.New(x =>
{
    x.RunAs("username", "password");
});
```

Of course you could read `username` and `password` from your `app.config` and, maybe, encrypt these values.

If you want to impersonate another user there's not much you can do but use some low-level api.
Here you can find a good [explanation/solution](http://www.cameronjtinker.com/post/2014/02/06/On-the-Fly-Windows-Impersonation-with-C.aspx).

Comment: I want to impersonate the authenticated user, whoever that may be.

Comment: I've done it using code but rather than having to write the code I would prefer to set it in the web.config - but think you are right; not possible without IIS.  Although I theorize you still using a webserver of some kind when self-hosting?  I do have a solution for my problem - which is to use interception to intercept all calls and wrap with impersonatation code.